# Is there a way to set a breakpoint at a multiline function defined in a let block in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Using ghci, if I have something like

```
1 g x y = 
2     let -- ...
3     in -- ... (recursively calls itself) 
3 
4 
5 f x = -- ... (calls g once)
```

I can set a breakpoint at g using `:break g`, call f, and have the program break every time g gets called.

However, I'm not using g anywhere else, so I would like to write

```
1 f x =
2     let g x' y =
3         let -- ...
4         in -- ...
5     in -- ...
```

Is there a way to break every time g gets called? I noticed that if g is one line, I can just say `:break 2`.

I can also break at the let statement for g, using `:break 3`; but, I would like to bind the arguments g gets called with, and I don't think that lets me do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GHC 9.0.1 a feature has been added to allow you to break on nested functions. See [the GHC 9.0.1 user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#setting-breakpoints). E.g.:

```
> :break f.g
```

For earlier versions of GHC, you could perhaps add a special debugging variable:

```
debugBreak = True

f x =
    let g x' y | debugBreak =
        let -- ...
        in -- ...
    in -- ...
```

Then you can break on that function like this:

```
> :break debugBreak
```

And just do a single step when you hit that break point.